# How do I install a subversion client on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, apt, svn

I tried:

`sudo apt-get install subversion`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package subversion is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'subversion' has no installation candidate
```

I need a command line version for supporting builds which were developed under Ubuntu 14.xx and use `svn`.

Comment: The subversion package does exist for 16.04 as shown on this search of the package lists http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=subversion&searchon=names&suite=xenial&section=all perhaps try `sudo apt-get update` before the install command.

Comment: Please execute `sudo apt update` and then post the output of `apt-cache policy subversion`

Comment: Please [edit] your post to include the output of `lsb_release -a`

Comment: Yes!  The 'sudo apt-get update' before getting subversion fixes the problem.  Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

```
sudo add-apt-repository universe
sudo apt update
sudo apt install subversion
```

Works on Ubuntu Server 18.04.